# Quorum Enterprise Ethereum - PrivateFor Parameter Passed When Instantiating Contract and/or During Calls to Contract?

Tags: quorum

In Quorum, when using privateFor, do we put the PrivateFor parameter during the contract creation and/or during the call to the contract itself?

1. Only during the creation of the contract
2. Only during making a function call to the contract
3. Both -- during the creation of the contract and the function call

Nathan Aw (Singapore)

Answer (score 1):

In Quorum, for private side of things, privateFor is required at all txns, including contract creation.